# UnboundID LDAP SDK bind using current user's windows credentials

Tags: java, windows, ldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

Is is there a way to retrieve the current user's login credentials from a windows machine and use them to bind an LDAP connection using UnboundID's LDAP SDK?

I need to avoid asking for the user's credentials or storing any credentials in the application itself.

EDIT: At this point I am not explicitly bound to using UnboundID LDAP SDK. If there are alternatives that provide this functionality I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use IWA authentication http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_Windows_Authentication and then to retrieve the user information using UnboundID's LDAP SDK